# Number format errors in a custom google fusion tables infowindow

Tags: javascript, formatting, google-fusion-tables

Thanks in advance.  So i have a custom tabbed infowindow that opens using a addlistener event.  The tabs work correctly (images, text, links) but my number values displayed are strange, for example my cost (in fusion tables) is 10.00 but in the info window it appears as 10.00000000.  How to I round this to 2 significant figures?

I've tried:

1. setting the format in google fusion tables.
2. using javascript, for example Math.round(((e.row['Cost'].value)*100)/100).  Interestingly, this just removes all decimal places and produces 10.

Here's a portion of my code

```
google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function(e) {
if(infowindow) infowindow.close();
else infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    infowindow.setContent(
    '<div class="tabs">' +
'<ul>' +
'<li><a href="#tab-1"><span>tab 1</span></a></li>' +
'<li><a href="#tab-2"><span>tab 2</span></a></li>' +
'</ul>' +
'<div id="tab-1">' +

 '<b><div class="infowindow_row">Cost:</b> ' + e.row['Cost'].value + '</div>' +     
 .........................
```

Comment: Can you share a link to your site and Fusion Table? Thanks!

Comment: The testing site is http://www.anacostia.net/maps/tabtest.php.   Thanks for any help you can give me.  Another thing to note is that its using a merged table, but i also made sure the parent table columns were set to show two decimal places.

Comment: Hmm.. I don't have access to the site. Is it possible to share a link to the table instead? If the table is private, please feel free to send the link to googletables-feedback+kathryn@google.com. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks for looking into the problem and to the greater coding community for being so helpful, but i answered my own question this time (based on others questions).   This method brings the numbers in as a string, I simply had to parsefloat, round the number and fix the number to 2 places for instances that the number ended in a 0.

```
var apDA =  (Math.round(parseFloat(e.row['Cost'].value)*100)/100).toFixed(2) ;
```

Its interesting that setting the number type in google fusion tables will affect how the number displays in the standard infowindow, but not when its parsed out as I did above.

Answer (score 0):

The rounding with multiplying by 100 and all that is superfluous. `toFixed` already does the rounding. From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp):

> Convert a number into a string, keeping only two decimals:
>
> > var num = 5.56789;
> >
> > var n=num.toFixed(2);
>
> The result of n will be:
>
> > 5.57